# Graphic design resources

Tags: resources, graphic-design

What resources would you suggest to start learning visual design from for someone well established in UX and interaction design up to the black-and-white wireframes level?

Answer (score 9):

Some resources you may find helpful:

1) Sites:

- [Graphic Design for the non-designer](http://www.villagecreative.com/blog/graphic-design-for-non-designers)
- [The Non-Designer's Design Workshop (minicourse resources)](http://www.nondesigners.com/minicourse/index.html)
- [Typography and Graphic Design 101](http://conceptcentral.blogspot.com/2008/05/typography-and-graphic-design-101.html)

2) Books:

- [The Non-Designer's Design Book: Design and Typographic Principles for the Visual Novice](http://www.amazon.com/Non-Designers-Design-Book-Typographic-Principles/dp/1566091594)
- [Graphic Design for Nondesigners: Essential Knowledge, Tips, and Tricks, Plus 20 Step-by-Step Projects for the Design Novice](http://www.amazon.com/Graphic-Design-Nondesigners-Step-Step/dp/0811868311)

Comment: Thanks! I started the Non-designer's design book some while ago but found it too much on the entry level. I'll definitely give it a try again.

Answer (score 4):

[50 Totally Free Lessons in Graphic Design Theory](http://psd.tutsplus.com/articles/web/50-totally-free-lessons-in-graphic-design-theory/) is a good place to start.

*"While many of us can create something that looks good in Photoshop or attractive when spliced into CSS, but do we actually understand the design theory behind what we create? Theory is the missing link for many un-trained but otherwise talented designers. Here are 50 excellent graphic design theory lessons to help you understand the 'Whys', not just the 'Hows'."*

Answer (score 3):

A big part of the puzzle is just learning the tools.  Almost everyone uses Adobe, but you have to choose your poison.

1. Illustrator.  Scalable/vector, best often if the work needs to be printed.
2. Photoshop. Bitmaps. General purpose.
3. Fireworks.  Heavily oriented towards web work.

I am a photoshop guy and I am constantly boggled by Fireworks and Illustrator.  Choose carefully and then do tutorials on the tool.  Once you learn the tool, then it's an issue of art theories like composition, balance, color theory, alignment, yadda yadda.  I love the book Universal Principles of Design to give an overview.

Online, SmashingMagazine.com is a wonderful resource for all things graphic design.

Comment: Just to be clear.  I find the others ones boggling because I have a lack of experience with them.  They are very powerful tools and fit particular tasks very well.